# Sorting a Dictionary by Double value Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a Firebase database with place names and coordinates, having fetched both and putting each of them into their own `Array` and then into a `Dictionary`, I want the `Dictionary` sorted by the nearest location/lowest `Double`.

I have looked at tonnes of previously asked questions and just can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. When I print my dictionary it orders them in alphabetical order (having crosschecked the (actual) distances I know they are correct).

How would I order by lowest `Double`?

```
var placeName = ""
var distanceArray = [Double]()
var nameDistanceDictionary = [String:Double]()
```

**Inside fetching data from Firebase**

```
self.placeName = placeSnap.key

let distanceRound = Double(round(10*distance)/10)
self.distanceArray.append(distanceRound)
self.nameDistanceDictionary = [self.placeName:distanceRound]
print(self.nameDistanceDictionary)


//Prints (example Doubles)
["Ascot": 5.5]
["Birmingham": 1.2]
["Bristol" : 18.6]
["London": 0.3]
["Manchester": 40.2]
["Newcastle": 2.4]
```

I've tried (This prints the same as above minus the `[""]`

```
for (k,v) in (Array(self.nameDistanceDictionary).sorted {$0.1 < $1.1}) {
    print("\(k):\(v)")
    }
```

Comment: Basically a dictionary is always unordered. The `for` loop creates an **array** of tuples from the dictionary. And your example prints multiple dictionaries with one key/value pair respectively.

Comment: So because I'm creating multiple dictionaries it _is_ ordering them, but there is only one value for it to order?

Answer (score 3):

Every item in your dictionary has two properties:
**key** and **value** ([more about dictionary here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary))

You don't have to create Array from your dictionary. Just sort your dictionary by item value.

```
.sorted(by: {$0.value < $1.value})
```

now create for each loop and instead of creating `k` and `v` just create `item` which will represent each item in your dictionary.

```
for item in ...
```

Now if you want to print value and also the key just use

```
print(item.value)
```

and

```
print(item.key)
```

Replace whole for each loop:

```
for (k,v) in (Array(self.nameDistanceDictionary).sorted {$0.1 < $1.1}) {
    print("\(k):\(v)")
}
```

with this

```
for item in nameDistanceDictionary.sorted(by: {$0.value < $1.value}) {
    print("\(item.key):\(item.value)")
}
```

Comment: It's still printing the exact same thing

Comment: @TsGDev really? Did you rewrite your whole for each loop?

Comment: I rewrote it as you said in the last code block, but it's still printing as it was in the beginning, I'm so confused

Comment: @TsGDev wait, does it print just one value?

Comment: It's printing both values like before, but they're not ordered by closest location (which would be lowest `Double`) - they're still ordered alphabetically

Comment: @TsGDev did you do exactly what I wrote above? Try to read it again and check if you didn't write something wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183584/discussion-between-robert-dresler-and-tsgdev).

Answer (score 1):

Your life would be a lot easier if you stored your model as a `struct` instead of trying to do some `Dictionary` hack. Try something like this:

```
struct Place {
    let name: String
    let distance: Double
}

let places = [Place(name: "Ascot", distance: 5.5),
              Place(name: "Birmingham", distance: 1.2),
              Place(name: "Bristol", distance: 18.6),
              Place(name: "London", distance: 0.3),
              Place(name: "Manchester", distance: 40.2),
              Place(name: "Newcastle", distance: 2.4)]

for place in places.sorted(by: { $0.distance < $1.distance }) {
    print(place.name)
}
```

Comment: The problem is I am getting the places from the Firebase database so what you said would be perfect, except for the places are coming from coordinates on a large database so cannot hard code it

Comment: @TsGDev You could try creating the Place struct when recieving your item from the database and appending it to a array.